# Crystal Enterprise PDF Files

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-server

I have a website that generates pdf file from CSP. Will this pdf file be generated in the server before showing to the user? WIll it be saved in the server? Is there a way to copy these files?

-Vivek

Comment: You may want to elaborate a bit more? So you're creating the PDF's and you want to copy them somewhere? YOu can use standard disk copy methods to copy these?

Comment: let me reframe my question.

When the Crystal server generates PDF file from a CSP, will it save the pdf somewhere in the server temporarily

Comment: are you generating these reports on a schedule or 'on demand'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you schedule a report, then the document is stored and managed by the File Repository server, regardless of output format (PDF included).  You will have pro-grammatical access to the 'instance' using the BO SDK.

If you ran the report on-demand, I believe that the document will be cached by the Page server, but I don't think you will have pro-grammatical access.  The File Repository server should clear the cached document when it expires.